# AngularJS bootstrap ui - how do I change css styles?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap UI with AngularJS directives and I want to change the default styles bootstrap applies for its elements.

Should I target the HTML contents from the template?

Based on the examples given in the documentation I want to use the [accordion](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#accordion).

When I define it in HTML, it has the following structure:

```
<accordion>
    <accordion-group heading="my heading">
      content here
    </accordion-group>
```

But when the directive processes the template it turns it into the following HTML:

```
<accordion close-others="oneAtATime"><div class="panel-group" ng-transclude="">
    <div class="panel panel-default ng-isolate-scope" heading="my heading">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" accordion-transclude="heading">
                    <span ng-class="{'text-muted': isDisabled}" class="ng-binding">content here</span>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" collapse="!isOpen" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="panel-body" ng-transclude=""><span class="ng-scope">some content here</span></div>
    </div>
```

As you can see, it changes it quite significantly. If I wanted to change how the panel title is displayed, should I write this in my css files?

```
div.panel {}
```

and hope that the template doesn't change in the future?

What is the best approach to changing styles for HTML elements generated by a directive's templates?

Comment: I don't quite have time to supply a proper, thought-out answer. But here's a Plunker I made in case anyone finds it useful: http://plnkr.co/edit/Bs9hCqCDkSmO4OtR716A?p=preview

Answer (score 6):

If you include your css (site-specific.css) after Bootstrap's (bootstrap.css), you can override rules by redefining them.

For example, if this is how you include CSS in your `<head>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site-specific.css" />
```

You can simply override the panel (in your site-specific.css file):

```
.panel {
    //your code here
}
```

And do not bother template change in the future. As you use a specific version, updates will not effect you. They are generating a new template with a new version name.

Comment: I am using `UI-Bootstrap version 2.1.3`. I want to style `<uib-accordion>` as per my needs. Applying CSS classes to `<uib-accordion>` isn't working. How can I do it?